# Read multiple macro-enabled Excel files

Tags: r, excel, file-io

I'm trying to read approximately 500 Excel files with marcos enabled, and I'm getting this error:

> Error: Skipped over all data

This is the code I used to run the program:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsm")
for (i in files){
  data <- ldply(files, read_excel, sheet = 'R1')
  data$file_name <- files
}
```

If I run the code for 10 to 15 macro-enabled files, I'm able to read the data. However, when trying to read in all files I get the above error.

Is there any way I can read these files? How can I debug this error?

Comment: I would start reading an increasing number of files and see at what point the code fails. That way you could rule out any potential file problems.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to increase number of files and run the code but still I'm getting the same error. This time I'm able to read the data for one macros files only. If I add one more file and run, it is showing skipped over all data. I don't why it is getting skipped. I will be really thankful if you can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
library(xlsx)
setwd("C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/files")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsm")
data <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 1))

for (i in data.files) {
    data <- rbind(data, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```